# CMake can't find QtCore

Tags: linux, qt, cmake

My project uses cmake which tried to look for QT4 which is installed:

```
root@netqa1:~# which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake

root@netqa1:~# ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Feb  6  2013 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Feb  6  2013 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Feb  6  2013 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2998336 Feb  6  2013 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
```

Still I continue to get this error from cmake:

```
Warning: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
Warning: But QtCore couldn't be found.  Qt must NOT be installed correctly, or it wasn't found for cross compiling.
```

Any pointers will be really helpful

Answer (score 16):

You have probably not installed QT4 dev packets. On Ubuntu this is something like `libqt4-dev`.

The suffix "dev" stands for development packet.

Comment: @ddahuja Did this solve your problem? It solved mine, please give it the CHECK MARK.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. on Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

Adding this option to `cmake` works for me in Kubuntu 18.04 :

```
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4
```

Original discussion [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51066).